# Wamp running fine over network but unable to view other sites

Tags: apache, wamp

I have created a multi site for wamp and this is working fine on the server pc but not sure how to access these sites from a network.  I put all the sites' folders just in the root of wamp, a folder before the 'www'.

here's a part of the apache conf

```
#virtual sites

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName client1.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/client1"

    <Directory "C:/wamp/client1">
        allow from all
        order allow,deny    
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
        ServerName client2.localhost
        DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/client2"

        <Directory "C:/wamp/client2">
            allow from all
            order allow,deny    
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </VirtualHost>
```

and here's the hosts entry

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1   client1.localhost
127.0.0.1   client2.localhost
127.0.0.1   client3.localhost
```

This works fine in the server's pc browser by going to x.localhost (x = client folders).  I changed the hosts file on the client pc to this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.0.100   main
192.168.0.100   client1.main
192.168.0.100   client2.main
192.168.0.100   client3.main
```

On the client's browser these urls all shows the main wampserver index.php and not its assigned folder/site.

Comment: Try to set <VirtualHost *:80> (port number instead of IP)

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? You have a muddle of 2.2 and 2.4 commands in your config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Apache 2.4.x this is more likely to work:

```
#virtual sites

#NameVirtualHost is no longer required in Apache 2.4.x so get rid of it.
#NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    # allow access from only this PC (security)
    Require local
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName client1.main
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/client1"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory "C:/wamp/client1">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        # allow access from any ip in my subnet but not the internet
        Require ip 192.168.0
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName client2.main
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/client2"
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory "C:/wamp/client2">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        # allow access from any ip in my subnet but not the internet
        Require ip 192.168.0
    </Directory>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Now your networked PC's should be able to find the correct site using the HOSTS file you have setup on each of them.

I dont know what this line in the hosts file was for so you could remove it.

```
192.168.0.100   main
```

So the network PC's have this as their HOSTS file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.0.100   client1.main
192.168.0.100   client2.main
192.168.0.100   client3.main
```

The client PC's then use `http://client1.main` to get to the first site and `http://client2.main` to get to the second .. etc

Of course you would then also have to address the sites from the PC running WAMPServer as `http://client1.main` as well. And change the HOSTS file on the WAMPServer PC to be the same as the ones on the network.